# Can't see how to change flood fill routine to DFS one

Tags: javascript, minecraft

I have been using a flood fill routine which checks for a certain type of block then finds all connected blocks of the same type and changes them to type "stone"
I am mainly interested in the coordinates of the blocks and would like to not change them but when I remove the "change to stone" statement it seems to run endlessly.
After researching it seem that a depth first search would work but not sure how to implement that - seem like I just need to tweek the flood fill but everything I try either endlessly loops or stops at the first iteration.
Here is the original program.

```js
//interact
var node1 = {
 xy : []
};
var blockp;
//starting block type and position
blockp = world.getBlock(npc.getBlockX(), npc.getBlockY() - 1, npc.getBlockZ() + 1);
node1.xy[0] = npc.getBlockX();
node1.xy[1] = npc.getBlockZ() + 1;
node1.xy[2] = npc.getBlockY() - 1;
//
var floodfill = function (nameb, node) {
 if (nameb == "minecraft:stone" || nameb == null) {
  return;
 }
 var blkname;
 var xy0 = node.xy[0];
 var xy1 = node.xy[1];
 var xy2 = node.xy[2];
 //
 //Line I would like to remove
 world.setBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1], world.createItem("minecraft:stone", 0, 1));
 //
 // collect x y z positions for all blocks
 world.getTempData("X_corr").push(node.xy[0]);
 world.getTempData("Y_corr").push(node.xy[2]);
 world.getTempData("Z_corr").push(node.xy[1]);
 //
 node.xy[0] = xy0;
 node.xy[1] = xy1 + 1;
 node.xy[2] = xy2;
 if (world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]) == null) {
  blkname = null;
 } else {
  blkname = world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]).name;
 }
 floodfill(blkname, node);
 //
 node.xy[0] = xy0;
 node.xy[1] = xy1 - 1;
 node.xy[2] = xy2;
 if (world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]) == null) {
  blkname = null;
 } else {
  blkname = world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]).name;
 }
 floodfill(blkname, node);
 //
 node.xy[0] = xy0 + 1;
 node.xy[1] = xy1;
 node.xy[2] = xy2;
 if (world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]) == null) {
  blkname = null;
 } else {
  blkname = world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]).name;
 }
 floodfill(blkname, node);
 //
 node.xy[0] = xy0 - 1;
 node.xy[1] = xy1;
 node.xy[2] = xy2;
 if (world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]) == null) {
  blkname = null;
 } else {
  blkname = world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]).name;
 }
 floodfill(blkname, node);
 //
 node.xy[0] = xy0;
 node.xy[1] = xy1;
 node.xy[2] = xy2 + 1;
 npc.say("go up " + blkname);
 if (world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]) == null) {
  blkname = null;
 } else {
  blkname = world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]).name;
  npc.say("go up " + blkname);
 }
 floodfill(blkname, node);
 //
 node.xy[0] = xy0;
 node.xy[1] = xy1;
 node.xy[2] = xy2 - 1;
 if (world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]) == null) {
  blkname = null;
 } else {
  blkname = world.getBlock(node.xy[0], node.xy[2], node.xy[1]).name;
 }
 floodfill(blkname, node);
 //
 return;
}
floodfill(blockp.name, node1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start of with the reason why floodfill never ends: It doesn't know when it has to stop, because none of the blocks change. The program thinks its never encountered the block before, and looks through it again, and again, and again...

Depth First Search is a search method that goes deeper until it can no more. When you bump into the end of one part you go back until you come across an item you've not seen before and dive as deep as you can in anything connected to that.

Breadth First Search is quite the opposite. It checks what is connected to your startpoint, checks them all, then checks all of their children, and their children, and so on.

Because you want to find ALL of the blocks that are connected to eachother, it makes no difference which one of these search methods you choose, because they will find all items in the same O(n) complexity.

I personally don't know anything about what you're trying to make, but I'm trying to keep this as universal as possible.

For either of these searches, `block` should have a variable called `visited` or something similar, that you can use to signal whether you've encountered this block before or not. You will probably have to create this variable yourself.
You also need a way of finding all the `block`s a `block` is connected to and return this as an array or list. In the examples, I'll call this function `neighbours()`.

To implement a DFS, you'd need a [Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29). A stack is a LIFO datastructure, meaning what came in last is the first thing to come out. Putting something into the stack is called a `push`. Taking the item back out is called a `pop`.

Here is pseudocode for a DFS:

```
DFS(Block start) {
    Stack stack = new stack();
    stack.push(start); // Put the first block in the stack
    while(stack.count > 0) {
         Block current = stack.pop();

         if(current.visited)
              continue; // if we've already seen this block, don't bother 
         current.visited = true;

         /* YOU CAN DO ANYTHING YOU WANT WITH THE BLOCK HERE */

         Block[] neighbours = current.neighbours();
         foreach(neighbour in neighbours)
              stack.push(neighbour);
    }
}
```

A BFS is different and slightly more appropriate for what you are trying to do. It uses a [Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) to store everything it needs to search through in a First In First Out order. This means that things farther down the search tree will be searched later, which is generally more appropriate for any search. Adding something to a queue is called `enqueue`, and getting the next thing out is called `dequeue`.

Here is pseudocode for a BFS:

```
BFS(Block start)
    Queue queue = new Queue();
    queue.enqueue(start); // Put the first block in the stack
    while(queue.count > 0) {
         Block current = queue.dequeue();

         if(current.visited)
              continue; // if we've already seen this block, don't bother 
         current.visited = true;

         /* YOU CAN DO ANYTHING YOU WANT WITH THE BLOCK HERE */

         Block[] neighbours = current.neighbours();
         foreach(neighbour in neighbours)
              queue.enqueue(neighbour);
    }
}
```

As you can see, both search methods are very similar, and they both run in O(n) [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

Good luck coding!